# How to write an if statement that checks if input has any letters

Tags: java, regex, if-statement

I need a regex that gives me true when a letter exists in the input.
I have tried `if (formula.contains("[a-zA-Z]+") == true)`, but this does not seem to work.

Hi! I figured it out!
`formula.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*")`
this worked!

Comment: Do you have any suspicion why it doesnt work?

Comment: Check the JavaDoc of `String#contains` :) Does it expect a regular expression or a substring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `String#matches(regex)` for this and a correct [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) of course

```
if (formula.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*")) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The regular expression hereabove means

```
.             Any character
 *            Zero or multiple times
  [a-zA-Z]    One letter in ranges a-z or A-Z
          .   Any character
           *  Zero or multiple times
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
"123".codePoints().anyMatch( Character::isLetter  )
```

> false

```
"123x".codePoints().anyMatch( Character::isLetter  )
```

> true

```
"à la carte".codePoints().anyMatch( Character::isLetter  )
```

> true

## Unicode property `isLetter`

There are many more letters in Unicode than just a-z, A-Z.

The [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) class provides a [`isLetter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(int)) method to indicate if a given character is a letter as defined by the [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) standard.

The [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) class offers the [`codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) method to return a stream of `int` numbers. Each number represents a [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepoint), the number that Unicode assigns to each of its 143,859 characters.

The [`Stream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) method runs a [predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) against each element in the stream's sequence. This method stops when it finds the first hit, the first element in the stream for which the predicate returns `true`. This is call [*short-circuiting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), meaning the work stops after the first found.

For our predicate test, we use that `Character.isLetter` method.

```java
boolean containsLetter =
        "123"                                
                .codePoints()
                .anyMatch(
                        codePoint -> Character.isLetter( codePoint )
                );
```

We can shorten that by using a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) with a pair of COLON characters.

```java
boolean containsLetter =
        "123"                                    // `String` instance.
                .codePoints()                    // Returns an `IntStream`, a stream of `int` integers, one for each character’s Unicode code point number.
                .anyMatch(                       // Runs a predicate test against each element of the stream, stopping after the first to return `true`. 
                        Character :: isLetter    // Method reference for static method `Character.isLetter( int codePoint )`. Serves here as our `Predicate` test object for the `anyMatch` call.
                );                               // Returns `true` at the first letter found, or `false` if no letter found.
```

### Avoid `char`

Notice that we do *not* use the `char` type. That type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the 143,859 characters defined by Unicode.

Comment: Could be with the method reference `public boolean hasLetter(String str) { return str.codePoints().anyMatch(Character::isLetter);}`

Comment: @AlexRudenko Thanks! I used your tip in my revised code.

Answer (score 3):

[`String#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) does not treat its parameter as a RegEx.

You can use [`Matcher#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) with the regex pattern, `\p{L}` which [specifies any letter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Test
        Stream.of(
                    "123",
                    "123a456",
                    "1a2b",
                    "@£$%^&"    
                ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + hasLetter(s)));
    }
    
    static boolean hasLetter(String s) {
        return Pattern.compile("\\p{L}").matcher(s).find();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123 => false
123a456 => true
1a2b => true
@£$%^& => false
```